# mysql multiple indexes for small sets of values

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table for logging data into, example

```
TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_log` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`channel` tinyint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`confirmed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY HASH (user_id)
PARTITIONS 11 */ AUTO_INCREMENT=4569
```

(Note - I know it should be InnoDB, but this isn't the question)

Regarding searching, it can be searched on user_id, user_id and channel, or user_id and channel and type.
user_id could be any number. 
channel is 1-20. 
type is 1-3.

Now user_id seems an obvious candidate to index, but would I need to index channel and type being that they are a relatively small set of possibilities?

Comment: Do you mostly read or write into this table? You can probably add combined index on user_id,channel.

Comment: Probably 80% inserts
10 % updates
10 % selects

Comment: Then probably you don't even need other indexes (unless some selects are slow), because adding index can slow down inserts and updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case when you have searches based on `user_id` `channel` and `type` you can use covering index (composite) which would be efficient.

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

So you may add the index as

```
alter table message_log add index search_idx(user_id,channel,type)
```